# Бесконечный поток java

Tags: java, многопоточность, websocket

В приложении из main-метода в отдельном потоке запускаю websocket-сервер:

```
try {
    server.start();
    while(true){}
} catch (DeploymentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    server.stop();
}
```

Чтобы сервер "бесконечно" ждал новые подключения, нужно, чтобы этот поток не завершался после старта сервера. Пока для этого просто поставил бесконечный цикл while, но он сильно нагружает процессор. Какой может быть способ поставить на паузу метод?

Comment: Может быть полезно http://frolov-lib.ru/programming/javasamples/vol8/vol8_6/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучший вариант - не делать лишнего потока там, где он не нужен. Если бы `server` работал в указанном потоке, а не создавал нового - то было бы проблемой меньше :)

Или, как вариант, надо отметить поток, в котором сервер слушает соединения, [основным](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) (`.setDaemon(false)`) - и просто убрать вызов `server.stop()`, ведь очередь до него никогда не дойдет.

Что же до вашей задачи - вам подойдет любой способ засыпания навсегда или надолго:

- `Thread.sleep(дофига)` в цикле
- `Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(); lock.lock(); lock.newCondition().await();`
- простой `Object obj = new Object(); synchronized (obj) obj.wait();`

Если же нужно еще и предусмотреть механизм остановки, то самый простой способ - `System.console().readLine()` вместо цикла - остановит сервер по нажатию Enter.